# Open firewall port on Fedora 14

Tags: linux, security, fedora, firewall

I want to open the port 18680 on my remote Fedora 14 machine. I did

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 18680 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 18680 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo service iptables save
```

The status returned is OK.

I have also opened the port on my security group on Amazon. Also, I rebooted the machine.

When I use the browser to view the application running at port 18680 the browser cannot connect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the AWS management console.

1. Go to **Amazon EC2** TAB
2. Click on **Instances** and note the **Security Group Name** from the **Security Group** column for the instance you want to open it for.
3. Click on the link **Security Groups**
4. Click on the **Security Group Name** from step 2.
5. You should see a dropdown, click it and select **Custom**
6. Enter:

   > ```
   > Protocol                  TCP
   > From Port                 18680
   > To Port                   18680
   > Source (IP or Group)      0.0.0.0/0       -- NOTE 1
   > ```
7. Click Save.

---

On Fedora to open a port on the ipables firewall you would either run the command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dports 18680 -j ACCEPT
```

or directly edit the config file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 18680 -j ACCEPT
```

Then save the changes with:

```
service iptables save
```

---

**After that you can verify** if the port is open with the command:

```
netstat -tulpn | less
```

And make sure the rule is in place with:

```
iptables -L -n
```

or

```
service iptables status
```

---

**Also if u ever need** you can restart iptables with:

```
servce iptables restart
```

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting but still it is not working.